# where are the configuration file for setting login screen, grub background and other customizeables?

Tags: login-screen, customization

I'm looking to customize different aspects of ubuntu and really don't know where to start any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Most of them are in /etc, though some—perhaps the login screen stuff—will not be. I would suggest a) being more specific, and b) asking multiple specific questions, such as "where are the login screen settings" and "how to set the grub background."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Ubuntu Tweak](http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Ubuntu_Tweak) is a very nice and powerful tool to configure system settings.